# Is it possible to put elementary OS on a CD/DVD disc instead of a flashdrive?

Tags: system-installation

I am currently using Ubuntu. Is it possible to create live CD/DVD of elementary OS instead of creating live usb(flash drive).

If possible, how to create?

Answer (score 5):

The elementary OS `.iso` file is too large to fit on a CD, so you will need to either burn it to a DVD or else make an elementary live USB using a flash drive that has at least 2GB.

To burn on DVD from Ubuntu: see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

Steps copied from the [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu):

- Insert a blank DVD. A 'CD/DVD Creator', 'Choose Disc Type' or 'Blank Disc' window might pop up. Close this, because we will not be using it.
- Go to downloaded ISO file
- Right click on the ISO file and choose 'Write to Disc'.

  [image]
- Where it says 'Write disc to', you might have options such as 'File image' as well as your CD drive. Choose your CD drive.

  Your CD drive might show as something like 'BD-MLT UJ-210S'.

  You can use `disks` to find exact name.

  [image: img]
- Start the burning process.

Reference and source for screenshots:

[How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

For more alternatives see:

[How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-to-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)